# Disabling non-secure access for only one URL on one instance of apache

Tags: https, apache2

For example, one instance of apache is managing

> www.site.com/folder1/a.html
>
> www.site.com/folder2/b.html
>
> www.site.com/folder3/c.html

I need to make sure that access to 
`www.site.com/folder3/c.html`
is https only.

All these folders are in the same document root.

Is this possible?  If not, what you recommend as the minimum changes necessary in order to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something in the Apache configuration like:

```
RedirectMatch /folder3/(.*) https://www.site.com/folder3/$1
```

Not sure if that's proper though.

Hope that helps...

Comment: This results in an infinite redirection loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/folder3/c.html$ https://www.site.com/folder3/c.html$1 [R,L]
```

With this solution you can also define which kind of redirection to apply. And, the most important, the rule will only run when in HTTP scheme.

Comment: This looked so technical that I thought it must be right!  However I can't get any response from this code. Is there some preliminary step I need to take before using this code?